Extracting simulated tokens from a simulated transaction
Was just looking at the old spl-token project on solana. Came across this in some code - where import * as Token from spl-token: Version 3 looks like.
function unpackTokenAccount(
    pubkey: PublicKey,
    accountInfo: SimulatedTransactionAccountInfo,
): Token.Account {
    const data = Buffer.from(accountInfo.data[0], 'base64');
    const tokenAccountInfo = Token.unpackAccount(pubkey, {
        data,
        executable: accountInfo.executable,
        lamports: accountInfo.lamports,
        owner: new PublicKey(accountInfo.owner),
        rentEpoch: accountInfo.rentEpoch,
    });
    return tokenAccountInfo;
}

const preSimTokenAccount = unpackTokenAccount(
                new PublicKey(accountOfInterest),
                preSimState,
            );
const postSimTokenAccount = unpackTokenAccount(
                new PublicKey(accountOfInterest),
                postSimState,
            );

This is slightly older code, and I wanted to know what the modern spl-token equivalent of it was? Where you get the reponse from a simulated transaction (in this case JITO's where they send the pre and post transaction), and the 'unpacking' it is doing.
